# Wifi not working after update on 14.04.4 LTS

Tags: 14.04, drivers, wireless, broadcom, secure-boot

I am using 14.04.4 and after when I update my software via software updater I cannot see my wifi connections after a reboot. I used dual-boot with windows and secure boot is turned on. Secure boot was enabled at the first place and I don't want to turn it off. How can I address this problem? I am using Broadcom BCM43142 adapter.

Comment: What is the result of the command: `sudo modprobe wl`?

Comment: required key not found

Comment: Please see: http://askubuntu.com/questions/762254/why-do-i-get-required-key-not-available-when-install-dkms-modules-or-after-a-k/762255#762255

Comment: So, is there no other way except disabling secure boot?

Comment: I'd certainly try the *mokutil* method first.

Comment: Aren't both the methods identical? How _mokutil_ method is different? Please explain.

Comment: @chili555 Please explain I am new to linux and thus need your help

Comment: The *mokutil* method allows your Ubuntu partition only to boot in insecure mode. Disabling secure boot in the BIOS (UEFI) allows both Windows and Ubuntu to boot in insecure mode; an alternative I gather you do not wish to pursue. It is not without its own issues, however:  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mokutil/+bug/1600615

Answer (score 1):

The actual reason is during the upgrade it removes some packages in ubuntu. One of the package might be the WiFi driver of the system. So, what I did in this situation is I visited the Ubuntu community documentation page which details all about [WiFi drivers](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver).

Follow the [documentation guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx) if this did not work

#### This instruction is for Broadcom only

To identify the wifi driver type the following command

- If it's an Internal card

  `lspci -vvnn | grep -A 9 Networ`
- If it's an USB card

  `usb-devices`

Now you have to download the driver from the documentation page and extract  the folder inside the package to the desktop. Then open the folder. In the folder right click on the window showing the WiFi driver content and click `"Open in terminal`". Then you have to type the following command below in order.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get --reinstall install bcmwl-kernel-source
```

Now you're done. Check if the WiFi works.

Answer (score 0):

I used "BLOG SLONIA" from POLAND For ubuntu 12.04-14.04 thanks

Run the terminal and type:

## Sudo passwd

We give the root password, then:

## Su

Command prompt:

## Apt-get update

## Apt-get remove bcmwl-kernel-source

The problem is confirmed by Y enter.
After unpacking the package and removing the dkms module, we include:

## Apt-get install the firmware-b43-installer

## Apt-get install b43-fwcutter

## Modprobe b43

## Ifconfig wlan0 up

And finally we restart the system with the command:

## Restart

After restarting our computers is what we need

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! Please link the source you are quoting and [format the commands](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code) properly.